# High Sierra Install but Disk is Locked

Tags: hard-drive

I was up all night trying to install Sierra and it would almost complete and give me an error. I deleted the disk and spent another 3 hours trying to install Sierra and it wouldn’t do anything.

I wake up this morning and it looks like it’s going to install and the disk is locked. I don’t know how this happened. And through all this mess I had deleted the disk image from disk utility.

Now there it isn’t letting me do anything to the disk, I can’t erase or partition it. Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: What Mac are you trying to install this on?  Sierra is quite old now, is there a reason for this version?  Did you try El Capitan?  I always thought it was more stable than Sierra anyway.

Comment: Sierra or High Sierra? The title does not reflect the question.